# Accessing Joomla CMS through iPhone using REST API

Tags: ios, rest, joomla

I have a web site that is built using Joomla CMS 1.5

I need to access articles in my iPhone app?
Is there is a REST API (or non-REST API) for Joomla that provide access to articles?

I have found [Joomla-REST-API](https://github.com/techjoomla/Joomla-REST-API) but it does not provide access to articles...

Comment: I have found this extension https://github.com/plexicloud/Plexicloud-JWS , it seems to support articles fetching (GET).